# "Create Order" shipping issue in Magento 1.9.2 - No quotes available for some (not all) customers

Tags: customer, shipping, import, cms

I have a site we imported 12,000 customers to (via the dataflow IIRC) and they're employing a company to create orders from the Admin - they've reported an issue where they can't select a shipping option before putting it through.

**Steps to recreate:**

- Go to Orders > Create Order and select an imported customer
- Add the product and select "Get Delivery Methods And Rates"
- After a second, the message is replaced with
  "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time."

I should mention that I do use WebShopApps Product Matrix.

Now I know what you're thinking: "he has the shipping set up incorrectly!!". I ensure you that they're all fine as it works with customers that were created and not imported.

**Here's the odd part (and the reason I'm posting this message).**

If I:

- Find the problem customer in the CMS
- Click "Save"
- Retry the above steps

It then lets me select shipping!

I've compared troublesome customers with updated customers (as I thought maybe there was an issue with assigning customers to no store) but I couldn't see anything untoward.

**So I'm wondering if:**

a) There's a way of batch "saving" customers so it fixes whatever link that's bridged when I resave the customer. We tried batch re-assigning all customers to the "General" group but that didn't seem to work (and timed out)

b) Adjusting something so it doesn't bring up that dastardly Quotes message.

Your help would be most appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have figured out why. It's because some imported customers didn't have a country code assigned to their address.

So for example, customer X was imported and their details appear in Magento like so:

[image: Without country]

So where the arrow is, no country. Loading the customer auto-populated the Country dropdown to United Kingdom, so when the page was saved, the Country then appeared.

[image: With country]

So once I go to process the order, the shipping is selected!

I've found a slight (if not slightly annoying) workaround where if you open the address drop down in the create order window, change the country and back again, the correct value is passed through and the shipping is accepted.

Now onto the massive task of updating all customers' countries :-(

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/313671/57334 can i get help thanks